# connected and path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have a discrete topological space consisting of the whole set the empty set and $\{0\},\{1\}$ .... I have shown it is not connected as both $\{0\}, \{1\}$ are clopen, however is this enough for me to say that it is not path connected either?

Comment: yes, since a path connected space must be connected (through the non-trivial fact that $[0,1]$ is connected).